# How can I auto generate column values (description) in sheet 1 matching column value (ID) from sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 worksheet in excel

Sheets contain column 1 (ID), Column 2 (Description)

I want to match sheet 1 column ID in sheet 2 and get value from sheet 2 column description in sheet 1 column description.

I hope I was able to mention my problem.

Comment: Sounds like you should use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Index() with match() will also work.